# Python: upgrade my own package

Tags: python, pip

I created and installed a python package by doing the following: coding a bunch of functions in an **init**.py file and run  'python setup.py install dist' to create a tar.gz, which was installed through pip.
Everything works well and I can import the package and the functions.
I decided to add a new function in the init file, and redid the whole procedure described above to reinstall (or update) my package. 
The new function added doesn't seem to be available when importing the package, even after update.
Any ideas on how to update my package?

Comment: If you are actively developing the package, consider doing `python setup.py develop` instead, so that changes are immediately reflected onto the environment.

Comment: Do what @metatoaster said, or do `pip install . -e`.

Comment: Thank you metatoaster, as you said changes weren't reflected immediately in the environment. Your command made changes instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @metatoaster suggested,  `python setup.py develop`  reflects changes immediately in the environment, and makes the new functions available.
I haven't tried @Paul H's suggestion which is  `pip install . -e`.
Thank you both for your comments, problem is solved.